# How to add a callback plugin to a PlaybookExecutor in Ansible 2

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

How to specify a callback when calling ansible via its API?

I have a callback plugin `database_write.py` for ansible 2.0.0.2 that logs into a database when this is run:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt playbook.yml # callback is fired ok
```

This works ok because in my $PWD i have `ansible.cfg` with this line:

```
callback_plugins   = ./src/callback
```

Now I'm trying to make ansible to execute my playbook and my callback using the python API. I've basically copied what the ansible-playbook cli tool does

```
# based on https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.0.0.2-1/lib/ansible/cli/playbook.py
pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=['../playbook.yml'],
                        inventory=inventory,
                        variable_manager=variable_manager,
                        loader=loader,
                        options=options,
                        passwords=passwords)

results = pbex.run()
```

This executes the playbook fine, *but the callback is not triggered.*

I guess when using the python API, my `ansible.cfg` file is not being taken into account?

**how do I specify my callback plugin to the PlaybookExecutor?**

(most of the documentation I've found works for ansible versions < 2.0)

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

2.0 API is very raw and generally not suited for end-user. It's likely to be changed in the future also. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ansible-devel/Vuhg_rElDjk/discussion) on mailing list where I posted similar question and proposed my own answer that apparently was correct: you can assign your callbacks to TaskQueueManager instance of the executor (PlaybookExecutor._tqm._stdout_callback).

```
pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=playbooks, inventory=inventory,
                        variable_manager=variable_manager,
                        loader=loader, options=options,
                        passwords=passwords)
cb = ResultAccumulator()
pbex._tqm._stdout_callback = cb
results = pbex.run()
```

(ResultAccumulator is callback plugin class from [here](http://infrastructure.fedoraproject.org/cgit/ansible.git/tree/scripts/builders/isbuilding.v2). It should be derived from ansible.plugins.callback.CallbackBase.

Answer (score 4):

Ansible API docs are scarce. PlaybookExecutor does not accept any callback arguments. 
However, you can create a custom callback from CallbackBase.
Here's an example which returns a list of all the TaskResults:

```
class SampleCallback(CallbackBase):
    """Sample callback"""

    def __init__(self):
        super(SampleCallback, self).__init__()
        # store all results
        self.results = []

    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result, **kwargs):
        """Save result instead of printing it"""
        self.results.append(result)

pbe = PlaybookExecutor(
            playbooks=playbooks,
            inventory=inventory,
            variable_manager=variable_manager,
            loader=loader,
            options=options,
            passwords=passwords
        )
callback = SampleCallback()
pbe._tqm._stdout_callback = callback
return_code = pbe.run()
results = callback.results
```

Answer (score -1):

With my setup (ansible 2.0.0.2 RHEL6 python 2.6.6) I needed to have it set in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
and did it thusly:

```
callback_plugins = /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback
bin_ansible_callbacks = True
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
```