# Ansible Playbook Retry Logic Using Python API

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

Using the Ansible 2 Python API I'm able to run playbooks and handle results with a custom callback handler (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019916/how-to-add-a-callback-plugin-to-a-playbookexecutor-in-ansible-2)). Everything works well, but now I'd like to implement a simple retry loop for the PlaybookExecutor.

All my callback handler is doing is stuffing any failed tasks in an array, and if I see that the array isn't empty count it as a failure and try again.

I have another python module that uses this script to kick off the playbook. The call to run_playbook is nested in a try/except block and I'd like an exception to bubble up so I can properly handle the failure.

I'd like to give my playbook 3 attempts at running and if all fail then raise an exception.

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function
import logging
import os
from collections import namedtuple
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase

class ResultsCallback(CallbackBase):
    """ A callback plugin used for performing an action as results come in """
    def __init__(self):
        super(ResultsCallback, self).__init__()
        # Store all failed results
        self.failed = []

    def v2_runner_on_failed(self, result, ignore_errors=False):
        if ignore_errors:
            self._display.display("...ignoring", color=C.COLOR_SKIP)
        host = result._host
        self.failed.append(result.task_name)


def create_inventory_file(hostnames):
    inv_file = 'ansible_hosts.{0}'.format(os.getppid())
    logging.print('\nCreating Ansible host file: {0}/{1}'.format(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), inv_file))
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), inv_file), 'w') as host_file:
        # If ec2, stuff into an '[ec2]' group.
        # Otherwise don't use a group header
        if 'ec2' in hostnames[0]:
            host_file.write('[ec2]\n')
        for host in hostnames:
            host_file.write('{0}\n'.format(host))

    return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), inv_file)


def run_playbook(hostnames, playbook, playbook_arguments, host_file=False):
    # If user passes in the optional arg host_file, then just use that one.
    if not host_file:                                                                                                                                                                                          
        host_file = create_inventory_file(hostnames)
    if not os.path.isfile(host_file):
        logging.critical('Host file does not exist. Make sure absolute path is correct.\nInventory: {0}'.format(host_file))
        raise RuntimeError('Host file does not exist')

    loader = DataLoader()
    inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=host_file)
    variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)

    # Add extra variables to use in playbook like so:
    # variable_manager.extra_vars = {'name': 'value'}
    if playbook_arguments:
        variable_manager.extra_vars = playbook_arguments

    Options = namedtuple('Options', ['listtags', 'listtasks', 'listhosts', 'syntax', 'connection','module_path', 'forks', 'remote_user', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'verbosity', 'check', 'diff', 'ask_sudo_pass'])

    if 'superuser' in playbook_arguments:
        remote_user = playbook_arguments['superuser']
    else:
        remote_user = 'ec2-user'

    options = Options(listtags=None, listtasks=None, listhosts=None, syntax=None, connection='smart', module_path=None, forks=100, remote_user=remote_user,  become=None, become_method='sudo', become_user='root', verbosity=None, check=False, diff=False, ask_sudo_pass=None)

    pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, options=options, passwords={})

    callback = ResultsCallback()
    pbex._tqm._stdout_callback = callback

    logging.print('Provisioning cluster with Ansible...')
    attempts = 3
    for i in range(attempts):
        try:
            pbex.run()
            failed = callback.failed
            if failed:
                logging.critical('Playbook failed!')
                raise RuntimeError('{0} tasks failed'.format(len(failed)))
            break
        except:
            if i < attempts - 1:
                logging.critical('Attempting to re-try playbook')
                continue
            else:
                raise

    logging.print('\nRemoving Ansible Inventory file {0}'.format(host_file))
    try:
        os.remove(host_file)
    except OSError:
        pass
```

However, when I test the above code using a playbook that is guaranteed to fail, it fails with the following traceback:

```
Creating Ansible host file: /home/someuser/ansible_hosts.18600
Provisioning cluster with Ansible...
Playbook failed!
Attempting to re-try playbook
Exception during setup; tearing down all created instances
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage_aws.py", line 486, in cmd_ec2_create
    manage_ansible.run_playbook(hostnames, playbook, playbook_arguments)
  File "/home/someuser/manage_ansible.py", line 88, in run_playbook
    break
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py", line 159, in run
    result = self._tqm.run(play=play)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py", line 296, in run
    strategy.cleanup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/__init__.py", line 223, in cleanup
    self._final_q.put(_sentinel)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 100, in put
    assert not self._closed
AssertionError
```

You'll notice that the exception is properly caught inside of the calling script manage_aws.py ("Exception during setup; tearing down all created instances") and we go to tear down the instances. That's great, but I'd like to properly re-try the playbook before deciding to do so.

I'm no Python master, so if anyone has any tips, or has accomplished something similar, then I would very much appreciate your advice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, and while it isn't as graceful as I was hoping it works.

The problem that I was having seemed related to re-running on the same PlaybokExecutor object without letting the spawned threads cleanup properly.

What I did to fix it was just initialize a new PlaybookExecutor object when I notice that the first failed. Current implementation allows for only one retry, which is fine, but I'll most likely adapt it to do more if necessary.

Here is my adapted retry logic:

```
    pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, options=options, passwords={})

    callback = ResultsCallback()
    pbex._tqm._stdout_callback = callback

    logging.print('Provisioning cluster with Ansible...')
    pbex.run()
    failed = callback.failed
    if failed:
        logging.critical('Playbook failed! Attempting retry...')
        pbex_retry = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, options=options, passwords={})
        callback_retry = ResultsCallback()
        pbex_retry._tqm._stdout_callback = callback_retry
        pbex_retry.run()
        failed_retry = callback_retry.failed
        if failed_retry:
            logging.critical('Playbook failed again! Failed on task:\n{0}'.format(failed_retry[0]))
            remove_inventory_file(host_file)
            raise RuntimeError('Playbook failed to successfully configure the cluster.')

    remove_inventory_file(host_file)
```

Super simple solution, but it is a shame my initial try didn't work out as intended. Maybe I'll re-visit it and try to properly cleanup the executor when failing.